# How to bring MDI Child Form To Front?

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent, topmost, bringtofront

**Overview:**

I have an MDI Parent Form in which I load other forms. After loading the second form, I can no longer bring the first one to the front.

**Description:**

On the parent form I have a menu strip containing 2 menu items; Home and Search.
Each click event loads their corresponding form unless said form is already loaded.

**The problem:**

**a.** Click Search. Then click Home.

**b.** If Search is once again clicked, it no longer brings its corresponding, already opened form to the front.

```
    private void tsmHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop through all open forms...
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            // If frmHome is Opened, set focus to it and exit subroutine.
            if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmSearch))
            {

                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        // If frmHome is not Opened, create it. 
        frmHome f = new frmHome();
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
    }

    private void tsmSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop through all open forms...
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            // If frmSearch is Opened, set focus to it and exit subroutine.
            if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmSearch))
            {

                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        // If frmSearch is not Opened, create it. 
        frmSearch f = new frmSearch();
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
    }
```

Comment: It appears that, if I comment out //return; it works as intended however, it creates new forms of the same type. Thoughts?

Comment: Grant, whichever really. I just want the user to click on a menu item, and have its corresponding, already opened form, brought to the front.

Comment: I just wanted to say I hate your name.  That is all.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working for me.. After changing one line in your `tsmHome_Click` event handler

You had.

```
if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmSearch))
```

It should be.

```
if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmHome))
```

Looks like a copy paste error got you.

Comment: A second set of eyes can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try several options:

```
f.TopMost = true;
f.BringToFront();
```

Also, you can open the window in Dialog mode:

```
f.ShowDialog();
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can change code to this, if form exist make it bring to front.

```
   // Loop through all open forms...
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        // If frmSearch is Opened, set focus to it and exit subroutine.
        if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmSearch))
        {

            form.Activate();
            form.BringToFront();
            //form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            return;
        }
    }

    // If frmSearch is not Opened, create it. 
    frmSearch f = new frmSearch();
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Form form in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
{                
    if (form.GetType() == typeof(Tviewer))
    {       
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;                     
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        return;
    }
}
```

//It worked for me.